# How do you simulate low memory in the Android emulator?

Tags: java, android, mobile

Is there an easy way to simulate low memory inside the emulator ?
I'm interested to perform resource cleanups similar to [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/59b726243404440b/720d28bd1bc3fcee)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Invoke [`ulimit`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ulimit) command from the shell.

```
ulimit -Sv 10000
```

This will set current memory limit to 10 000 Kb, so that all apps invoked from this shell afterwards won't be able to access more memory.

Comment: I get "ulimit: illegal option -v" when I try to perform this command.

Comment: on which shell? Is it `commond prompt` or `telnet`?

Comment: I get ulimit: virtual memory: cannot modify limit: Invalid argument

Comment: The "shell" into which the ulimit command has to be entered seems to be the one you can open by using _"adb.exe"_ (Android Debug Bridge). If only one Emulator instance or device is there, then you can just enter _"adb shell"_ in the DosBox (assuming that you are in the directory where adb.exe is located, namely _"sdk/platform-tools"_).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much! (Almost six years later, lol)

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking to trigger your onTrimMemory callbacks, then this will do the trick:

adb shell am send-trim-memory

e.g. adb shell am send-trim-memory com.example.app MODERATE

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this, if your phone or emulator has application Dev Tools (each emulator has). Open Dev Tools, navigate Development Settings and turn on "Immediatly destroy activities" checkbox. This can help you emulate situation when your activity destroyed as on low memory

Comment: it doesn't do things like clean the cache though.

Comment: This does not sends any trim memory events and hence not a true simulation of low memory.