# Simulate low battery & low memory in Android

Tags: android

In order to generate the notifications i need to know about how to generate the low battery and low memory interrupts programmatically. Can any one please provide your suggestions.I am aware of Intents.

Comment: You need to override `onTrimMemory(int level)` in your code in order to handle memory events.

Comment: Low memory https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.empirical.android.application.fillmemory

Answer (score 65):

To trigger your `onTrimMemory` callbacks:

`adb shell am send-trim-memory <process-name> <level>`

e.g. `adb shell am send-trim-memory com.example.app RUNNING_MODERATE`

Comment: Perfect.  I also like `RUNNING_CRITICAL` to get the full effect.

Comment: @MaksimDmitriev I get that error when using a physical device, but it works for me on emulator

Comment: `adb shell am send-trim-memory com.myapp MODERATE`
`Error: Failure to set the level - probably Unknown Process: com.myapp`. Any idea why? That package definitely exists. Also, I'm having a hard time finding documentation on that command.

Comment: Solved it. The error message is wrong (the key is the word 'probably'). What actually was happening in this case is that it wasn't recognizing MODERATE, despite the fact that it's listed as a valid level. Using `RUNNING_CRITICAL` worked.

Comment: @AutonomousApps it won't let you send a TRIM_MEMORY level that is invalid for the current state of the app. For example, if your app is in the foreground then it will fail to send the trim event for any level higher than TRIM_MEMORY_RUNNING_CRITICAL. This took me over 10 minutes to figure out.

Comment: this only works on an EMULATOR, on my real device I always had errors like: "Unable to set a higher trim level than current level" or "Unable to set a background trim level on a foreground process"

Answer (score 54):

Low memory can also be simulated using `Background process limit` under the device developer options.

Go to `Settings > Developer options`. Under the `app` section change the `Background process limit` to **No background processes**

Now your activity will be killed every time you switch to another app. Useful for testing state saving and state restoration.

Comment: Sadly this is not true at all. Here is [great explanation](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/62393) what exactly this option does.

Comment: I have an app with bg services and push notifications enabled, the app won't be killed as for other apps.

Answer (score 16):

yes, this api triggers the same callback you would get if you registered a context to ComponentCallback2, specifically the [ComponentCallback2#onTrimMemory](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentCallbacks2.html#onTrimMemory(int)) this wasn't mentioned here, so I thought I'd make it clear. The syntax for this command is:
`am send-trim-memory [--user <USER_ID>] <PROCESS>               [HIDDEN|RUNNING_MODERATE|BACKGROUND|RUNNING_LOW|MODERATE|RUNNING_CRITICAL|COMPLETE]` 
**Note: this command is only available on devices running Marshmallow+**

Comment: Very true. I could only get this to work on devices running Marshmallow and above.

Answer (score 6):

On the Android Emulator you can [set the power status by connecting to the Emulator console and using the `power` command.](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#power)

As far as low memory goes, you just need to make sure that your application can handle being killed without warning when it is in the background.  Testing this is one of the very few cases that actually call for a Task Manager on Android, or if you're running Android 2.2 you can kill applications via Settings.

[There are ways of reducing the memory available to applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483047/how-do-you-simulate-low-memory-in-the-android-emulator) but I think they're unnecessary.

Comment: Hi Dave Webb, I want to do it programmatically to show an low battery alert even though it is not.

Comment: Hi Dave Webb, In emulator its ok. But how can i do the same in real device..?

Comment: There isn't a way to make a phone show a low battery alert when the battery is not low.

Answer (score 4):

To simulate low Battery warning, try this command in the way answered by Frank:

```
power capacity 10 // It will set the battery level into 10%
```

For low Memory:

```
ulimit -Sv 15000  //The current memory limit will set to 15000 Kb
```

Comment: i am running the application in device and in DDMS view, i could see the heap memory viewer and i see the heap memory allocated as 18.2 MB. Using your command i set current memory as 1500. So why application did not crash or allocated memory did not reduce ?

Comment: @Prem, After 'telnet' to 'localhost 5554', I'm trying 'ulimit' command. But always it is returning error 'KO: unknown command, try 'help''. I'm using Win7 OS. Pls help me.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky I searched, it's a shell build-in command which exists in most of Linux OS, including Android. So you can run it by `adb shell ulimit -Sv 15000`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the emulator menu. Just telnet to localhost on the port of your emulator (default is 5554) and then type help. Follow the instructions from there!

Answer (score 1):

To trigger the memory trim event, an app can be used that fills all the RAM of the device, and that triggers the event.

There are many on the Play Store, they can be found by searching for 'fill ram'.

Answer (score 0):

A great way to make sure the app is actually killed is to... **kill it**.

As of now (Dec 2023), you can use the "kill process" context menu option inside the Logcat window.

1. Hide your app
2. Kill it, using this menu
3. Resume your app
4. -> Application.onCreate() is called
5. -> Your app will resume to its original state (if it handles state well)

Use "Kill process", as "Force stop application" will not allow you to resume to the previous state.

P.S. Not sure why, but I don't see this option elsewhere in the GUI.
[image]