# Simulate battery discharging

Tags: android, android-emulator

I built a service that checks the phone battery, but I do not know how to test it. How to simulate battery discharging in the Android emulator? Something like: put value 25% level, 10% and others ...

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this question help?
[Simulate low battery & low memory in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656594/simulate-low-battery-low-memory-in-android)
Seems you may be able to do it the emulator.