# Android app gets killed when gallery is opened

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm trying to resolve some mysterious behavior when my application gets killed when I'm in gallery.

I have such flow:

From `Activity_1` I'm `startActivityForResult` `Activity_2`. From `Activity_2` I'm letting user to pick an image from desired source.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Hint", REQUEST_CODE_SELECT_PICTURE);
```

Sometimes while user is in the gallery (usually when there are lots of apps in the background running) my app gets killed. Without any warning whatsoever - my application process disappears from process list. And when user picks a photo he's able to return to `Activity_2` but all previously selected images are lost.
If user presses "Next" at that point app should return to `Activity_1`

```
Intent data = new Intent();
data.putStringArrayListExtra(EXTRA_PHOTOS, new ArrayList<String>(selectedPictures));
setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
finish();
```

But it looks like there is no `Activity_1` and app just restarts. No crash, just restart. And user gets back to `Activity_1`, but looses all data.

It is very hard to reproduce and is very annoying. Is there a way to prevent such behaviour?

Comment: your app is killed because it is not in focus and your device is short on memory. you are supposed to save all the necessary data before you leave your app for that case.

Comment: Android's [Process Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Lifecycle) documentation has some details how it picks apps that get killed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android kills applications when he needs ressources.
So, in your case, the gallery needs more ressource and Android kills your application.

But your application is notified (via `onPause`, `onDestory` etc) when it's happening , you need to save your application state via **`onSaveInstanceState()`** and get it back together when your application returns

Comment: Is there a way to reproduce "resource starvation" manually? I mean with 100% reliability for easy testing?

Comment: Here similar question on SO : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656594/simulate-low-battery-low-memory-in-android

Comment: Killing process or application did not work for me. It would kill the gallery app too as it is in same process. You should use `Immediately destroy activities` in [developer options](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-devtools.html). This simulates desirable conditions.

Answer (score 1):

I can't be 100% sure, but this sounds normal for Android. If there are in fact a lot of apps running, Android will kill apps, if they're not in focus (the activity is not being displayed).

This should be handled by properly implementing the activities' lifecycle methods. You can save the state there and recreate it once Android creates a new instance of your activity. You can read about it here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html