# Android onTrimMemory testing

Tags: android, memory, genymotion

How can I simulate **TRIM_MEMORY_RUNNING_LOW** in Genymotion or on a real device? Can I send a command from **Android Studio** or per command line (with *adb*)?

I really need to test it, while my app is in front and not in background.

Comment: You can use `adb shell am send-trim-memory` (see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33048675/2577986)