# Android IntentService triggered with null intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-intentservice

I'm seeing a crash in Crashlytics:

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke
>   virtual method 'int
>   android.content.Intent.getIntExtra(java.lang.String, int)' on a null
>   object reference
>          at com.myapp.APKOfferQueueManagerIntentService.onHandleIntent(SourceFile:71)
>          at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>          at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

How can it be that an IntentService is being triggered with a null intent?

Comment: Have you called onStartCommand in service?

Comment: No I didn't add onStartCommand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An `IntentService` may be stopped like every other service, but it will be restarted by "the system" until `onHandleIntent()` has finished its work. In this case, the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html#onHandleIntent(android.content.Intent)) says the *intent* parameter

> ... may be null if the service is being restarted after its process has gone away

To always get the original `Intent` as a parameter, use

```
setIntentRedelivery(true);
```

in the constructor of the `IntentService`.

Note also that

> If multiple Intents have been sent, only the most recent one is guaranteed to be redelivered.

Comment: This sounds like the solution. Is there a way I can simulate an intentService being abruptly killed and then called again? I'd like to verify the solution.

Comment: @JY2k - I'd try something like a [task killer app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Tasks/Nukesalot) - or maybe this [SO post by Xavi Gil](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26253635/5015207) will be useful