# Handle situation when Intent is null during onHandleIntent

Tags: android

I have the following `IntentService`.

```
public class NotificationIntentService extends IntentService {
    public NotificationIntentService() {
        super("NotificationIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
        boolean retainStockPriceAlert = intent.getBooleanExtra(RETAIN_STOCK_PRICE_ALERT, true);
        ...
    }
}
```

---

I start the `IntentService` using the following code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationIntentService.class);
intent.putExtra(NotificationIntentService.RETAIN_STOCK_PRICE_ALERT, retainStockPriceAlert);
startService(intent);
```

However, to my surprise, some users are getting null `Intent` during `onHandleIntent`. Hence, NPE happens.

From documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html#onHandleIntent(android.content.Intent)

> Intent: The value passed to startService(Intent). This may be null if
>   the service is being restarted after its process has gone away; see
>   onStartCommand(Intent, int, int) for details.

I'm not quite understand what does it mean by `restarted after its process has gone away`.

I can easily avoid NPE by

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
    if (intent == null) {
        return;
    }

    boolean retainStockPriceAlert = intent.getBooleanExtra(RETAIN_STOCK_PRICE_ALERT, true);
    ...
}
```

But, I'm not sure whether that is a correct thing to do.

Comment: Is the intent null or it does not have extras?

Comment: The intent itself is `null`.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37973523/3022836) might be the reason why Intent is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I able to avoid NPE by using

```
setIntentRedelivery(true);
```

in `IntentService` constructor

This answer is provided by @Kunu 's reference linkt - https://stackoverflow.com/a/37973523/72437