# Unknown command 'send-trim-memory' Android

Tags: android, android-memory

Iam trying to trigger low memory events using android studio's terminal:

```
To trigger your onTrimMemory callbacks:

adb shell am send-trim-memory

e.g. adb shell am send-trim-memory com.example.app MODERATE
```

but i get this message Unknown command 'send-trim-memory' . Iam using emulator on the latest android.

Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33048675/1531971 (Note that trim support was introduced at some later time https://stackoverflow.com/a/39595612/1531971)