# With a bound service, will onUnbind() be called along with onDestroy() if system decides to kill the service?

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding, android-binder, android-binding-adapter

If a service is deemed unimportant, it might be killed by the system. I am aware that `onDestroy()` is not guaranteed to be called when the process is killed too but in situations where the calls go through (like if the service is killed while process is still kept alive), is `onUnbind()` called along with `onDestroy()` to release the binder, or is `onUnbind()` specifically reserved to be called after `unbindService()`, as such only `onDestroy()` will be called?

I would also like to have a clarification on the exact conditions for `onServiceDisconnected()` to be called and if it related to the same problem. My current guess is that it gets whenever the service is killed without an `unbindService()` call. Am I right to think so?

I have tried testing it by using ADB commands like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656594/simulate-low-battery-low-memory-in-android) to simulate a low memory environment but even with the `RUNNING_CRITICAL` setting, bound service was not being killed, so I could not test it.