# How to reproduce low state memory on Android device

Tags: android, cordova, camera, low-memory

In order to reproduce a bug, I need to create a low memory state on my Android device. The bug is related to the camera app that apparently kills my application when it get started. The app is based on Phonegap 1.4.1 and I have already read posts about this but I could not find a way to replicate the low memory state.

Comment: A simple SO search yields [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483047/how-do-you-simulate-low-memory-in-the-android-emulator) answer

Comment: Thanks but it's the first I have done and it didn't help me. I get a "ulimit: Illegal option -v"

Comment: The 'v' stands for 'The maximum amount of virtual memory available to the process.' http://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html

Comment: There is more that one valid answer to the linked question.

Answer (score 1):

In developer options on android, choose "Don't keep activities" at the end of the page

Comment: Also, setting the number of background processes may help