# How to emulate "low storage" in Android?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I want to emulate "low storage" scenario where only 1MB of internal storage space is available on Android Virtual Device.

I tried to change the internal storage space, but the minimum internal storage can be set to 200MB

Can someone please let me know if there is a way to do this?

Comment: see this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483047/how-do-you-simulate-low-memory-in-the-android-emulator

Comment: That link is for Memory not storage.